# Creating new column based on other column values with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column with values:

| brand |
| --- |
| Brand1 |
| Brand2 |
|  |
| Brand3 |

```
data.brand = data.brand.astype(str)
data.brand = data.brand.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
data['branded'] = np.where(data['brand']!= 'nan', True, False)
```

after first init of the code I get results:

| brand | branded |
| --- | --- |
| Brand1 | TRUE |
| Brand2 | TRUE |
| nan | TRUE |
| Brand3 | TRUE |

after second init of the same code I get desired results:

| brand | branded |
| --- | --- |
| Brand1 | TRUE |
| Brand2 | TRUE |
| nan | FALSE |
| Brand3 | TRUE |

What could be the smarter way to face/avoid this problem?

Comment: replace this `data.brand = data.brand.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)` with `data.brand = data.brand.replace(r'^\s*$', 'nan', regex=True)`?

Comment: You can also avoid using `replace` and `np.where` part because you are just checking the values in `brand` for presence of  full whitespace characters and this can  be simply achieved using `str,contains`. Please check `data['branded'] = data['brand'].str.contains(r'^\s*$')`

Comment: Thanks! data.brand = data.brand.replace(r'^\s*$', 'nan', regex=True) fixed it!

Comment: data['branded'] = data['brand'].str.contains(r'^\s*$') this gives inverse of wanted results

Comment: @A99 Just invert the mask check `data['branded'] = ~data['brand'].str.contains(r'^\s*$')`

Comment: @ Shubham Sharma this raises:
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'NoneType'

Comment: @A99 May be some of the values in column `brand` are `NaN`  in such case we need to pass optional parameter `na=True` in the `contains` method. You can try `data['branded'] = ~data['brand'].str.contains(r'^\s*$', na=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer just focusses on *Why did the first iteration not work*

In your code when you replace the `data.brand` with the `regex`, you replace with `np.nan` which is not `nan`, hence the first init cannot identify the condition in the next line : `np.where(data['brand']!= 'nan', True, False)`. However, on the second init, the row is already a `np.nan` and you do `.astype(str)` in the first line which sets `np.nan` to `'nan'` and hence the third line works.

Solution:

Replace:

```
data.brand = data.brand.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

With:

```
data.brand = data.brand.replace(r'^\s*$', 'nan', regex=True)
```

This will set the replace value to `'nan'` from the get go and hence the third line will run fine in the first iteration.